# 'Find Nearest' Equivalent in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, network-analysis

I'm a new user to QGIS, trying to solve a problem that I've encountered in ArcGIS Online. I want to run a 'Find Nearest' analysis, however the number of points I'm routing from is greater than 1,000. Is there a simple way to undertaken this task in QGIS? I need the distances to be based on the road network as opposed to crow fly distance.